# String indexOf method is not working for first character in the String

Tags: java, string, indexof

I am implementing a code for counting number of occurrences for all the characters in a String. I have used indexOf() method to check occurrences. But it's not working for the first character.
The following code works fine for all characters except the first character.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "simultaneously";
        int[] count = new int[str.length()]; //counter array

        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) { //initializing counters
            count[i] = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int index = -1;
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            while (1 > 0) {

                if (str.indexOf(c,index) > 0) {  //This is not working for 
                                                 //the first characters
                    index = str.indexOf(c, index) + 1;
                    count[i]++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(str.charAt(i) + " occurs " + count[i] + " times");
        }
    }
```

Comment: the condition `while (1 > 0)` is better wriiten as `while(true)`

Comment: No need to initialize array elements to zero: Java initializes a new array's elements to the default value by specification, and the default for int is zero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Index for arrays in java starts from 0.
Change the condition from

```
if (str.indexOf(c,index) > 0) {
```

to

```
if (str.indexOf(c,index) >= 0) {
```

And also, the for-loop to initialize the counter is redundant, by default, all the values in the int array is initialized to 0.

Answer (score 7):

`str.indexOf(c,index)` would return `0` for the first character, but your condition checks whether `str.indexOf(c,index) > 0`. Change it to `str.indexOf(c,index) >= 0`.

Answer (score 2):

There is some thing else you need to know

```
str.indexOf(c,index)
```

will search for the character c from the index 'index' which is -1 in your case for the first character that is it will never find this because starting point of string is 0
also change your condition as following

```
str.indexOf(c,index) >= 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The index of arrays and Strings (which are array of characters) always start at 0 in Java.

You also want to check position 0, so include >=.

```
       if (str.indexOf(c,index) >= 0) {
```

Also, using breaks can sometimes be confusing.
In your code, your while-loop is an infinite True and then you break out of it when necessary.

Take a look at this code below. It serves the same purpose that you want to accomplish.
It is much cleaner and clearer as it removes the break from the whileloop and you simply check to see if the statement is True at the beginning of the while-loop rather than inside it.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int index = 0;
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            while (str.indexOf(c,index) >= 0) {
                index = str.indexOf(c, index) + 1;
                count[i]++;
            }
        }
```